# Can I attach a website to a CMS without re-design/recreate it?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, content-management-system

I am developing a webiste in which i've already developed all HTML/PHP/CSS files, i.e. it's almost a finished and ready-to-publish website. Now I want to attach a webCMS to it, to allow admin to fill it with contents without my supervision.

I wonder if I can simply "attach" the website to the CMS and fill it, without make modifications to the website structure/design to accomodate CMS's templates or I have to redefine the entire website aspect into the CMS like theme customization in WP (with a obvious waste of time).

Comment: "I have a birthday cake. Can I add vinegar without affecting the rest of the cake?" is basically what you're asking, and the answer is: "maybe, probably not"

Comment: if pointing out the obvious is "smart ass", then so be it. You've provided NO details about your site, no details about the CMS, so how could we possibly answer with anything but generalities?

Comment: I didn't see anything impolite about Marc's answer

Comment: Take a look at Couch CMS. You just need to add a class to your div's which can be edited.

Comment: I haven't used it, but [Perch](http://grabaperch.com/) claims to be suitable for retro-fitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this depends on how many features of the CMS you want to use with your template.

As you already gave the example of WP:
You could create an really simple WordPress theme where you just put all your assets (CSS & JS files, images, etc) into a folder in `wp-content/themes/your-theme`) create a index.php with your html code and just place some very basic calls to the WordPress functions like [wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head), [wp_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) and [the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) into this file. This will give you the basic functionality of a CMS with little effort.

[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates) is a good tutorial to get you started.

When you want to use more advanced features (like theme customization, sidebars, custom page-templates or other advanced templating functions) you have to spend more effort obviously. If you are in need for this functions you may be better of restarting the whole thing and build it as a child-theme of an existing theme or atleast from a simple vanilla/base theme.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn your design into a template. Otherwise the CMS wouldn't know where to put the data in the HTML.